# Google Analytics Ecommerce Transactions not importing to AdWords

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

I have connected my AdWords and Analytics accounts and everything seems to be working, except transactions don't show up as conversions in AdWords.

In Analytics I can go to Conversions -> Ecommerce -> Overview and view my transactions.
I can also go to Aquisition -> AdWords -> Campaigns and see clicks and transactions (just 1 test transaction that I made) for my AdWords campaigns.

So the only problem is that I don't see the conversions in the AdWords dashboard. I went to Tools -> Conversions -> Google Analytics and setup the importing of transactions from the correct view in Analytics. Still not working!

EDIT: I also don't see Real-Time Conversions in Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Your Conversion is probably not showing, because it does not originate from clicking a google ad prior to the conversion. AdWords [only](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034306?hl=en) imports goals/transactions that can be tracked back to paid Google search ads.